# Verificar ip, cadastrar no array, converter para json e gravar em arquivo

Tags: php, json

Pessoal estou tendo um problema. Eu tenho um script em php que abre um arquivo json, decodifica com json_decode e depois verifica se no objeto json existe o ip do visitante atual, se tiver deixa para lá, mas, se não tiver, cadastra num array para codificar em json e gravar no arquivo json.

Minha dúvida é que não estou conseguindo fazer a checagem de cada ip e se não tiver ip cadastrar no array uma única vez. Estou usando for e ele repete cada ação do IF.

Veja o código da iteração:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_visitors; $i++){
    $ip = $decoded_json_stats[$i]->ip;

    if ($ip == $visitor_ip) {
        echo "tem cadastrado<br>";
    } else {
        echo "não tem cadastrado<br>";
    }
}
```

Onde ta o problema? Já tentei com foreach mas o ip já cadastrado era cadastrado de novo. Veja o código completo do meu script até agora.

```
<?php

/* Pegar o ip do visitante e cadastra no arquivo de estatisticas
*/
$visitor_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$fstats = file_get_contents("stats.json");
$decoded_json_stats = json_decode($fstats);
$decoded_json_to_array = json_decode($fstats, true);
$total_visitors = count($decoded_json_stats);

$a = "127.0.0.4";

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_visitors; $i++){
    $ip = $decoded_json_stats[$i]->ip;

    if ($ip == $visitor_ip) {
        echo "tem cadastrado<br>";
    } else {
        $new_visitor_array = array("ip" => $visitor_ip);
        array_push($decoded_json_to_array, $new_visitor_array);

        $new_json = json_encode($decoded_json_to_array);

        $file = fopen("stats.json", "w");
        fwrite($file, $new_json);
        fclose($file);
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Tenho um arquivo chamado **stats.json** que é onde irá ficar os ips cadastrados. Veja como ele está no momento:

```
[{"ip":"127.0.0.2"},{"ip":"127.0.0.1"},{"ip":"127.0.0.4"}]
```

Está em inglês o script por preferência minha.

*Obrigado!*

Comment: Não, verificar se um certo ip já tem no objeto e se não tiver cadastrar no array e depois transformar em objeto json para cadastrar no arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos percorrer os objetos json e ver se algum deles é igual ao ip do visitante (`$new_ip`, neste caso), sendo que neste exemplo o `$jsonRaw` virá do ficheiro no teu caso, ex:

```
$jsonRaw = '[{"ip":"127.0.0.6"},{"ip":"127.0.0.1"},{"ip":"127.0.0.4"},{"ip":"192.168.1.72"},{"ip":"192.168.1.73"}]';
$jsonDeco = json_decode($jsonRaw);
$new_ip = '17.0.0.1';
$found = false;
foreach($jsonDeco as $ip) {
    if($new_ip == $ip->ip) {
        echo 'tem cadastrado ' .$ip->ip. '<br>';
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$found) {
    $jsonDeco[] = array('ip' => $new_ip);
}
$new_json = json_encode($jsonDeco);
$file = fopen("stats.json", "w");
fwrite($file, $new_json);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: o que seria esse $unique? fwrite($file, $unique);

Comment: @Bruno, Isso foi outra tentativa... Esquece vou corrigir, desculpa fiz a primeira maneira como se quisesses retirar duplicados, e essa var acabou por ficvar por engano

Comment: Cara aqui funcionou perfeitamente bem! Substituir o jsonRaw pela chamada no arquivo stats.json e ta tudo ok! Obrigado

Comment: Pronto! Sinalizei a resposta

Comment: (: @Bruno, bem-vindo ao Stack overflow

Comment: Obrigado! =) !!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para verificar se o novo IP já consta em um array de IP's cadastrados;

```
$jsonRaw = '[{"ip":"127.0.0.6"},{"ip":"127.0.0.1"},{"ip":"127.0.0.4"},{"ip":"192.168.1.72"},{"ip":"192.168.1.73"}]';
$jsonDeco = json_decode($jsonRaw, true); # Converte o json para array

$new_ip = '127.0.0.6';

$has_ip = array_filter($jsonDeco, function($indice) use ($new_ip) {
    return $indice['ip'] == $new_ip;
});

if (empty($has_ip)) {
    array_push($jsonDeco, ['ip' => $new_ip]);
    ... # grava o array $jsonDeco após realizar o json_encode no arquivo
}
```

O array_filter vai retornar um array com com os ips encontrados na lista de ips, então, pode-se verificar se ele esta vazio ou não, caso esteja então o IP ainda não foi cadastrado.

Comment: Boa resposta, pensei nisso também mas acho que se for um json com milhares de dados teriamos de os percorrer todos, mesmo que encontrasse-mos a ocorrêcia no primeiro indice teriamos de percorrer os restantes desnecessariamente. +1, não deixa de ser uma boa solução

Comment: Obrigado mas a solução de Miguel já me serviu!